# Is there a way to pass condition in eloquent that if key exists then don't send object from collection (in mongodb)?

Tags: laravel, mongodb, eloquent

I am using jenssegers/laravel-mongodb,
I have a collection segments, I don't want those objects to be send by eloquent which has key named 'unrooted' i.e. to pass a condition to check if 'unrooted' key is set in collection, so I want

```
$condition[' ? '] = false;  // $condition unrooted exists is false.
$segments = Segment::where($condition)->get();
```

I know that it can be done like getting all the objects pass the condition, and then

```
foreach($segments as $key => $segment){
    if(property_exists($segment, 'unrooted')){
        unset($segments[$key]);    
    }
} 
dd(array_values($segments->toArray());
```

But it is not efficient for me incase of large collection.
Thankyou for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simple, just used mongodb docs, posting it here for future references.

```
$condition['$exists'] = false;
```

[$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/#exists) does the trick.